# How to create a callback for Google+ interactive posts?

Tags: javascript, callback, google-plus, jquery-callback

I'm using [Google+ interactive posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#interactive_share_button_attributes) that lets users post a prefilled message to their timeline.
I need to find a way to detect if the *interactive post* window faded out after the user clicked **share** or **cancel**.
Google doesn't offer a callback as far as I know, so is there an other way to detect if the window faded out?

Example code by Google:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();
</script>

 <button
  class="g-interactivepost"
  data-contenturl="https://plus.google.com/pages/"
  data-contentdeeplinkid="/pages"
  data-clientid="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-prefilltext="Create a Google+ page for your business."
  data-calltoactionlabel="CREATE"
  data-calltoactionurl="http://plus.google.com/pages/create"
  data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/pages/create">
  Tell your friends
</button>
```

There is an [interactive posts example by Google](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#interactive_share_button_attributes) at the bottom of the page, titled *Invite your friends*.